# (Electron JS) How can you make a program that automatically saves even after closing? Specifically like Microsoft Sticky Notes

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I want to ease the burden of my user in accessing a certain page in my desktop app without going back and forth again and again, thus my question. Think of it as Microsoft Sticky Notes and its an Electron JS desktop app. Even a Youtube link would be nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't save after the application is closed (stopped, has exited) but what you can do is: you can listen to the close event on the electron application and use that to store the data *when* the user closes the application. Simply implement a listener there that runs your store method.

Example:

```
browserWindow.on("close", evt => {
    // save-logic here
});
```